# Instanciar uma classe em Python utilizando um objeto como argumento

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou começando a trabalhar com Python e vi que não há como criar multiplos contrutores em uma mesma classe. Com isso eu pensei em passar para o contrutor `__init__` um objeto contendo os atributos da classe, como no exemplo:

```
class Foo(object):
    '''
    classdocs
    '''
    _id = None
    name = None

    def __init__(self, *attrs):
        if attrs:
            for key, value in attrs.iteritems():
                setattr(self, key, value)

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        if(hasattr(self, key)):
            return key
        else:
            return None

    def __setattr__(self, k, v):
        if hasattr(self, k):
            super().__setattr__(k, v)
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

O problema é que não estou conseguindo alimentar minha classe com os atributos existentes, sempre apresenta um erro. Quando eu crio uma instancia simples da classe sem passar atributos e defino manualmente os atributos, a classe também não restringe caso o mesmo não exista.

```
from Project.Models.Foo import Foo

c = Foo()

print(c._id)
print(c.name)
print(c.foo)
```

Ao fazer isso eu tenho o erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Project\src\Project\Test\TestFoo.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(c.foo)
  File "F:\Project\src\Project\Models\Foo.py", line 25, in __getattr__
    if(hasattr(self, key)):
```

Alguém tem uma idéia de como posso passar objetos para setar classes e como posso restringir os get e set caso o atributo não exista?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em tua necessidade no inicializador da classe, voce implementa key e valor. Isto caracteriza dicionário. Entretando a chamada esta utilizando a notação para listas.

Substitua:

```
    def __init__(self, *attrs):
    if attrs:
        for key, value in attrs.iteritems():
            setattr(self, key, value)
```

Por:

```
    def __init__(self, **attrs):
    if attrs:
        for key, value in attrs.iteritems():
            setattr(self, key, value)
```

E outra incongruência esta na implementação do `getattr`, pois o metodo `hasattr()`, roda o dundler getattr. Isto faz que a chamada entre em loop infinito.

Substitua:

```
def __getattr__(self, key):
    if(hasattr(self, key)):
        return key
    else:
        return None
```

Por:

```
def __getattr__(self, key):
    if key in self.__dict__:
        return self.__dict__[key]
    return None
```

Código completo disponível em:

https://gist.github.com/britodfbr/02b27c18bddc877ff25d8fdad9be9c0e

Comment: Cara já tinha até esquecido dessa pergunta mas isso com certeza resolve o problema que tive, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Respondi sua outra pergunta em [Restringir o __setattr__ quando o atributo não existir dentro da instância em Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151410/restringir-o-setattr-quando-o-atributo-n%C3%A3o-existir-dentro-da-inst%C3%A2ncia-em-py) com algo que deve resolver seu problema.

tem alguns erros de conceito em como você está escrevendo o que quer - 
Mas antes de abordar sua questão é importante teer em mente que "Python não é Java" em outra linguagem estaticamente tipada: você poder adicionar atributos a um objeto já existente é uma feature da linguagem - e geralementee, apesar de existirem formas, você não precisa se preocupar em colocar essas restrições artificialmente: perceba que as únicas pessoas que podem querer colcoar mais atributos num objeto são outros programadores  - e eles podem querer ter um uso para esses atributos - se não houver um uso, não há por que querer setar os tais atributos.

Isso dito - você está confuso sobre como usar "objetos" e dicionários - em Python - não como em Javascript - objetos e dicionários são diferentes - esses últimos tem características que chamamos de "mapping" - e, apesar de podermos setar e ler atributos dinâmicamente em objetos, se o nome dos atributos não é fixo no código fonte, o melhor é usar dicionários para isso -

No caso do seu exemplo, simplesmente passe "attrs" como sendo um dicionários - não precisa do `*` -

```
def __init__(self, attrs):        
    for key, value in attrs.items():
        setattr(self, key, value)
```

De novo - se quiser restrignir acesso a atributos, cheque minha resposta na questão linkada acima.

Comment: eu sei que Python não é java, mas isso não quer dizer que o meu conceito de OO voltado a uma classe que foi construído em Java não possa ser aplicado em Python. Entendo que os únicos que irão alterar os atributos de um objeto são os programadores mas se você tem uma equipe onde 1 designer estrutura o projeto, eles só poderão alterar conforme a classe definida pelo designer

Comment: "eles só poderão alterar conforme a classe definida pelo designer –" - exatamente - e em Python se entende que os programadores são 'consenting adults' - eles não precisam que a linguagem os obrigue a uma restrição que foi acordada na documentação ou por convenção em um projeto.

Answer (score 1):

Minha solução, depois de algumas dores de cabeça foi definir todos os atributos que eu poderia ter dentro dessa classe diretamente no método `__init__`. O que percebi foi que, diferente de Java, o Python não depende de um numero específico de variáveis na inicialização, contanto que estas tenham valores default. Assim

```
class Teste:
    foo = None
    bar = None
def __init__(self, foo=None, bar=None)
    self.foo = foo
    self.bar = bar
```

Fazendo isso, independente se eu declaro uma simples `t = Teste()` ele não irá me obrigar ter passado qualquer parâmetro na instância.