# Restringir o __setattr__ quando o atributo não existir dentro da instância em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Olá, preciso saber como posso montar uma classe que não possa ter atributos implementados após a instância. Ex:

```
class Foo(object)

    def __init__(self, a='hello', b='world')
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    __setattr__(self, key, value)
        if hasattr(self, key):
            super().__setattr__(key, value)
        else:
            pass
```

Estou tentando criar uma classe como essa mas não funciona porque mesmo eu verificando se o atributo existe na classe a instancia ainda define um novo atributo, ao invés de apenas ignorar...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Talvez você não precise declarar o `__setattr__` - 
O modelo de objetos do Python define o atributo especial
`__slots__` que, estando declarado numa classe e e em todas
as superclasses, restringe os atributos que os objetos da classe
poderão ter. (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots)

Além da restrição desejada, o atributo `__slots__` tem a vantagem de que o Python não precisa criar uma instância de um dicionário para cada instância da classe (essa é sua finalidade principal na verdade) - assim fazendo objetos que teriam o papel de uma pequena estrutura de dados terem um footprint de memória bem reduzido.

```
class Foo(object):

    __slots__ = ('a', 'b')

    def __init__(self, a='hello', b='world'):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

E no ambiente interativo:

```
>>> f= Foo()
>>> f.c = 5

    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-82-6ce08c4facb1> in <module>()
    ----> 1 f.c = 5


AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'c'
```

Comment: Antes eu usava uma variavel de condicao e executava uma funcao que obrigava o `__setattr__` a ler se a variavel estava true e então travava o objeto para novos atributos... usando o __slots__ realmente ficou menos "recurso-técnico" rs

Comment: um problema que identifiquei em relação ao `__slots__` é que se eu tiver "nested classes" definidas dentro da classe onde elas servem para complementar uma lista, o elemento __slots__ conflita com o da classe pai

Answer (score 1):

Você estava no caminho certo, acredito que seja mais um problema de erro de syntax do que outra coisa, veja esse exemplo:

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if not hasattr(self, key):
            return
        super().__setattr__(key, value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = Foo('a', 'b')
    f.c = 'c'
    print(f.c)
```

Basicamente é o mesmo código que você escreveu, com a diferença que o método `__setattr__` está escrito como um método corretamente.
Ao executar esse código, acontece um `AttributeError:`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "attr.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(f.c)
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'c'
```

Ou seja, o atributo `c` não foi criado no objeto, ele foi ignorado.

Porém, existe um efeito colateral, ao sobrescrever o método `__setattr__` com esse comportamento, nenhum atributo passa a ser aceito pela classe, ou seja, nem mesmo os declarados no método `__init__` (`a` e `b`).

Uma possível solução seria declarar um lista de atributos permitidos e se basear nessa lista, ao invés de verificar os atributos que o objeto possui:

```
class Foo:

    attributes = ('a', 'b')

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key not in self.attributes:
            return
        super().__setattr__(key, value)
```

Comment: Muito boa respoosta,  mas de uma olhada no `__slots__`

Comment: Vi sua resposta @jsbueno realmente muito melhor e mais assertiva. Já usei slots no intuito de diminuir o uso de memória na criação de milhares de objetos iguais, mas nunca pensei em usar para restringir os atributos de uma classe.